# VBA "error 5 en tiempo de ejecución"

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una macro que crea tablas dinámicas y selecciona los datos que necesito y me funciona perfectamente en mi ordenador donde tengo `Excel 2010`.

Lo he puesto en otro ordenador que tiene `Excel 2007` y me indica:

> Error 5 en tiempo de ejecución

Código donde me da el error:

```
Columns("A:I").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "EXTRACCION_DATOS!R1C1:R1048576C9", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="TABLA!R5C1", TableName:= _
    "Tabla dinámica1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es debido al momento de especificar el `PivotTable` o `PivotCache` por la versión de tu Excel.

En `Excel 2007`:

```
Columns("A:I").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"EXTRACCION_DATOS!R1C1:R1048576C9", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12). _
CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="TABLA!R5C1", TableName:= _
"Tabla dinámica1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [XlPivotTableVersionList Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpivottableversionlist-enumeration-excel)

Comment: Perfecto, incluso con una versión mas baja, también puedo usarlo con el que yo tengo. Muchas gracias,